# ASP Email with a recordset

Tags: database, vbscript, asp-classic, dreamweaver, recordset

Im designing in asp.

Need to send emails on a certain date by getting information in the table InspectionCalendar. (Access.)

On a specific day the will be more than one notification that needs to be sent.(Inspections)

How can I loop through the recordset by sending multiple emails by selecting one columns information in the each record that is available?

```vb
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject= (SmsInfo.Fields.Item("Subject").Value)
myMail.From= (SmsInfo.Fields.Item("Email").Value)
myMail.To= mail_to
myMail.HTMLBody= (Tag.Fields.Item("MaintenanceTag1").Value) &     (Agent.Fields.Item("Abreviation").Value) & (Reference.Fields.Item("MaintenanceID").Value) &     "." & (Tag.Fields.Item("MaintenanceTag2").Value) &     (Tag.Fields.Item("MaintenanceTag3").Value) & "."

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item     ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("schemas.microsoft/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("schemas.microsoft/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "localhost"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("schemas.microsoft/cdo/configuration/smtpserverpickupdirectory") = "c:\inetpub\mailroot\pickup"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 0 'basic (clear-text)     authentication 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
myMail.Send

set myMail=nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which recordset needs to be iterated? It looks like you've got four of them: `SmsInfo`, `Tag`, `Reference`, and `Agent`.

A basic recordset loop would look like this:

```
Do Until SmsInfo.EOF

    ' Call a SendEmail() routine (not shown) for each record in SmsInfo...
    SendEmail SmsInfo("Subject"), SmsInfo("Email")         

    SmsInfo.MoveNext

Loop
```

Comment: Sms Info Yes. Want to pull the subject and Date that is not listed above. Where do i put the recordset loop? before the Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")?

Comment: @user3501463 Seriously you managed to build a cdo mail configuration but you don't know how to loop a recordset?, smells like copy and paste syndrome to me.

Comment: Put your e-mail code in a separate subroutine. Then call it once for each record in your database, as I've shown above. Good luck.